# Is there a notion of the spectrum of $L^1$ functions and does it correspond with the support of a random variable?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

Is it possible to talk about the spectrum of a function? I know that $$A:=(L^1(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb C),+,*)$$ is a Banach algebra (the product operation ‘$*$’ is the usual convolution product). Therefore, for some function $f\in L^1$, we we can talk about the spectrum $\sigma(f)$, that is, the set of all scalars $\lambda\in \mathbb C$ such that $f-\lambda \mathbf{1}$ is not invertible in $A$.

Does this mean that the spectrum of an $L^1$ random variable kind of corresponds with the values it might take on?

---

**Edit:** The Banach algebra $A$ is not unital as pointed out in the comments, but one could in principle consider a unital algebra which contains $A$ (which always exists by general facts). In particular, one could consider the algebra $A_e=A\oplus \mathbb C$ with the obvious norm
$$\|(f,z)\|_{A_e}:=\|f\|_{L^1}+|z|$$
(where one morally adds the dirac delta to $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$).

Comment: On $\Bbb{R}^d$ with the Lebesgue measure, $L^1$ is a Banach algebra under convolution. I don't think such a thing exists in general.

Comment: How do you define multiplication on such functions?

Comment: @mihaild via convolution

Comment: How you define convolution on space without group structure?

Comment: @mihaild Let’s assume we are over R^n

Comment: What is $x$ in your definition of spectrum? It should be $f$. Anyway, I see a big obstruction here. The algebra $L^1$ typically does not have unit. Because the unit element would be the Dirac delta, which is not an element of $L^1$ (except trivial cases). So it does not make much sense to talk of "invertible elements", it seems to me.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think one can simply add a unitary element to a Banach algebra by taking the direct sum with $\mathbb C$ (if I am not mistaken). It is not clear to me what is the spectrum of an $L^1$ function (but maybe it’s just I am not familiar with this topic)

Comment: The fact that functions in $L^1$ are not invertible means that the spectrum of any function in $L^1$ contains $0$, and it is also a bounded set (bounded by the $L^1$ norm of the function). I don’t know what else can be said

Comment: @LorenzoPompili: that is equivalent to adding the measure $\delta_0$. In a way $L_1$ can be considered as a sub algebra in the space of finite Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz sure. There is more than one way of embedding $A$ into a unital banach algebra. Depending on the embedding, the answer might be different in principle. I chose to embed $A$ into $A\oplus \mathbb C$ just because it is the obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer. I consider the unital B.a. $A_e$ as in the edited question. The spectrum of a function $f\in L^1$ always contains $0$ and it is bounded by the $L^1$ norm of $f$. The question is, does it contain something besides zero?

Consider the Fourier transform $\hat f$ of $f$. On the Fourier side, the operator $f-\lambda \mathbf 1$ is the multiplication operator by the function $\hat f(\xi)-\lambda$. The inverse of this operator is the multiplication operator by the function $(\hat f(\xi)-\lambda)^{-1}$, and we want to know when this is an element of the algebra $A_e$. It is clear that, if $\lambda$ is in the range of $\hat f$, then the function $(\hat f(\xi)-\lambda)^{-1}$ is unbounded, and it cannot be the Fourier transform of some element of $A_e$. This argument implies that
$$ \overline{\operatorname{range}(\hat f)}\subseteq\sigma(f). $$
It is possible that the equality holds, it seems likely to me (and it would be quite a nice fact). I suspect this is something other people have done, but I couldn’t find a reference for that.

---

**Edit:** I think one can replace the $L^1$ norm by the $L^\infty$ norm of the Fourier transform and run the exact same argument again to obtain the equality. I am not sure on whether this makes sense though, I hope someone else will make this point clear.

Comment: This is extremely interesting thank you so much for writing this out! So the range of the ~Fourier Transform~ is contained in the spectrum of $f$, and the spectrum more corresponds to the range of the Fourier transform rather than the range of the function itself?

Comment: Here is an exercise from Rudin: Take $X=L^2(-\infty, \infty)$, suppose $\varphi \in L^{\infty}(-\infty, \infty)$, and let $M$ be the multiplication operator which takes $f \in L^2$ to $\varphi f$. Show that $M$ is a bounded linear operator on $L^2$ and that the spectrum of $M$ is equal to the essential range of $\varphi$ (Chap. 3, Exercise 19). Why might this spectrum correspond to the range of the function, and not, say, its fourier transform as in the L^1 case?

Comment: Yes, I am fairly sure they are the same thing (more precisely, the closure of the range). This seems to be closely related to the group structure of $\mathbb R^n$ (because I am using the Fourier transform). I suspect something similar works on $l^1$ and more general Lie groups.

Comment: It’s because in that exercise the operator you are considering is a multiplication operator, while in your question we are considering convolution operators. The Fourier transform maps convolutions to products, this is why it is very natural to consider it in this case.

Comment: Is this because L^\infty uses point-wise multiplication instead of convolution to make it a Banach algebra?

Comment: It’s not much because of the spaces, it is because of the nature of the operators. The spectrum of a multiplication operator is the range of the function, while the spectrum of a convolution operator is related to the range of the Fourier transform of the function. The difference is the kind of operator you are considering.

Comment: Is there any way to consider multiplication operators in an L^1 space? Could these correspond to unbounded operators of some kind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145140/discussion-between-lorenzo-pompili-and-sam-kirkiles).